# set up single directory ftp access for customer on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, amazon-web-services, users

I have a user who like to use the our Bitnami AWS ec2 instance to store podcasts. Up to this point they have been using http://www.lemonzdream.com/podcastmaker/ with MobileMe. Now that MM is dead, they just need some dedicated space to serve files from.

They aren't very tech savvy and setting up SFTP for them isn't ideal. I would like to give them a separate FTP account that will restrict access to a single web directory that they can upload to. The cloud image currently has a FTP server running but listening only in 127.0.0.1. The bitnami admin account is the only user.

Thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: What is the difficulty in having them use sftp?  There are many good FOSS clients, and it will probably be easier to setup, since you are already probably running an SSH server.

Comment: They are using a podcast app not a sftp/ftp client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install vsftpd

```
apt-get install vsftpd
```

First, be sure to open ports 35000:36000 on the firewall to permit PASV FTP.

Then for your `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
hide_ids=YES
use_localtime=YES
nopriv_user=ftp
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=ftp
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
ftpd_banner=My FTP Server
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
anon_upload_enable=NO
async_abor_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=35000
pasv_max_port=36000
pasv_enable=YES
port_enable=YES
write_enable=NO
```

Then to create a user, run,

```
/bin/htpasswd /etc/ftpd.passwd myusername
```

Then create the accompanying file in `/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/myusername`

```
guest_username=myuser
local_root=/home/myuser
write_enable=yes
```

The user connects as the `guest_username` stated, so it allows you to have multiple FTP users with different access, but all the while, preserving important file-level owner permissions.

That will give you a nice simple, chrooted, secure, isolated and manageable FTP configuration.

You're welcome.

Comment: Note that Bitnami users will need to install PAM, and that vsftpd is already installed. You will also need to comment #auth required pam_shells.so

Comment: does this work the same with sftp?