# FTP server configation

Tags: ftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [set up single directory ftp access for customer on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/408979/set-up-single-directory-ftp-access-for-customer-on-ubuntu)

I have installed Ubuntu 10.04 server in my server for the ftp configration

i want to configure in such a way that if i create a user in ftp  user should not see any other content

Please let me know for the configration

Thanks in advance 
sridhar

Comment: Please add more information to your question. For example, what FTP Server software are you using? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Install vsftpd

```
apt-get install vsftpd
```

First, be sure to open ports 35000:36000 on the firewall to permit PASV FTP.

Then for your `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
hide_ids=YES
use_localtime=YES
nopriv_user=ftp
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=ftp
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd_user_conf
ftpd_banner=My FTP Server
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
anon_upload_enable=NO
async_abor_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=35000
pasv_max_port=36000
pasv_enable=YES
port_enable=YES
write_enable=NO
```

Then to create a user, run,

```
/bin/htpasswd /etc/ftpd.passwd myusername
```

Then create the accompanying file in `/etc/vsftpd_user_conf/myusername`

```
guest_username=myuser
local_root=/home/myuser
write_enable=yes
```

The user connects as the `guest_username` stated, so it allows you to have multiple FTP users with different access, but all the while, preserving important file-level owner permissions.

That will give you a nice simple, chrooted, secure, isolated and manageable FTP configuration.

You're welcome.

Comment: Hi but i am using pure ftp in ubuntu server when i am using with same networking its working fine.  i want to access through the DNS but its not connecting.  when i trying through Fire ftp its waiting for passive mode